# Storybook can't resolve '@storybook/components'

Tags: storybook

Having an issue with my Storybook config.

Packages installed:

```
  "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.0.6",
  "@storybook/addon-console": "^1.0.0",
  "@storybook/addon-info": "^5.0.6",
  "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.0.6",
  "@storybook/addon-storyshots": "^5.0.6",
  "@storybook/addons": "^5.0.6",
  "@storybook/channels": "^5.0.6",
  "@storybook/react": "^5.0.6",
  "@storybook/theming": "^5.0.6",
```

`.storybook/config.js`:

```
import { configure } from '@storybook/react';
import '@storybook/addon-console';
import '@storybook/addon-links/register';

import { setDefaults } from '@storybook/addon-info';

// Allow jest mocking in Storyshots without affecting Storybook
global.jest = {
  mock: () => {}
};

const req = require.context('../app/bundles/', true, /\.stories\.jsx$/);

function loadStories() {
  req.keys().forEach(filename => req(filename));
}

setDefaults({
  inline: true
})

configure(loadStories, module);
```

Error message:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/code.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@storybook/components' in '/Users/briengivens/upstart/upstart_web/client/node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown'
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/code.js 23:18-50
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/index.js
 @ ./app/bundles/Shared/stories/AsyncDropdown.stories.jsx
 @ ./app/bundles sync \.stories\.jsx$
 @ ./.storybook/config.js
 @ ./storybooks/upstart/config.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./storybooks/upstart/config.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true
```

If I `yarn add -D @storybook/components`, then I get

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/tooltip/WithTooltip.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-popper-tooltip' in '/Users/briengivens/upstart/upstart_web/client/node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/tooltip'
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/tooltip/WithTooltip.js 46:49-80
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/code.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/index.js
 @ ./.storybook/config.js
 @ ./storybooks/upstart/config.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./storybooks/upstart/config.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true

ERROR in ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-syntax-highlighter/languages/prism/bash' in '/Users/briengivens/upstart/upstart_web/client/node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/syntaxhighlighter'
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter.js 50:35-91
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/code.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/index.js
 @ ./.storybook/config.js
 @ ./storybooks/upstart/config.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./storybooks/upstart/config.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true

ERROR in ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-syntax-highlighter/languages/prism/css' in '/Users/briengivens/upstart/upstart_web/client/node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/syntaxhighlighter'
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter.js 52:34-89
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/code.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/index.js
 @ ./.storybook/config.js
 @ ./storybooks/upstart/config.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./storybooks/upstart/config.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true

ERROR in ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-syntax-highlighter/languages/prism/jsx' in '/Users/briengivens/upstart/upstart_web/client/node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/syntaxhighlighter'
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter.js 48:34-89
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/code.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/index.js
 @ ./.storybook/config.js
 @ ./storybooks/upstart/config.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./storybooks/upstart/config.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true

ERROR in ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-syntax-highlighter/languages/prism/markup' in '/Users/briengivens/upstart/upstart_web/client/node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/syntaxhighlighter'
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter.js 54:37-95
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/code.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/index.js
 @ ./.storybook/config.js
 @ ./storybooks/upstart/config.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./storybooks/upstart/config.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true

ERROR in ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-syntax-highlighter/prism-light' in '/Users/briengivens/upstart/upstart_web/client/node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/syntaxhighlighter'
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter.js 56:42-89
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/code.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/index.js
 @ ./.storybook/config.js
 @ ./storybooks/upstart/config.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./storybooks/upstart/config.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true

ERROR in ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/form/input/input.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-textarea-autosize' in '/Users/briengivens/upstart/upstart_web/client/node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/form/input'
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/form/input/input.js 16:52-86
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/form/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/code.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/index.js
 @ ./.storybook/config.js
 @ ./storybooks/upstart/config.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./storybooks/upstart/config.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true

ERROR in ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/form/input/input.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'recompose' in '/Users/briengivens/upstart/upstart_web/client/node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/form/input'
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/form/input/input.js 14:17-37
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/form/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/code.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/index.js
 @ ./.storybook/config.js
 @ ./storybooks/upstart/config.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./storybooks/upstart/config.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true

ERROR in ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/tooltip/WithTooltip.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'recompose' in '/Users/briengivens/upstart/upstart_web/client/node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/tooltip'
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/tooltip/WithTooltip.js 42:17-37
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/code.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/markdown/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/index.js
 @ ./.storybook/config.js
 @ ./storybooks/upstart/config.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./storybooks/upstart/config.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true
```

Comment: Having the same issue. Temporary downgrading to 5.0.5 helps.

Comment: Do you have a reproduction repo somewhere I can check out?

Comment: did you solvate it? i am having the same issue...